# How to Show Null Values in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, null, jtable, tablemodel

I have a table that fetches data from a database. But in my database, sometimes some fields can be null values and `JTable` does not show these null values. I want to show  null values in my table as NA. How can I do that?

```
public void displayMovieTable(){
     try {

         PreparedStatement pr = conn.prepareStatement("select * from movie");
         ResultSet s = pr.executeQuery();
         movieTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(s));
         pr.close();

     } catch (SQLException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
}
```

Comment: Something like `String valueToBeSetInTable = (databaseValue == null) ? "null" : databaseValue;`? Just apply a check for `null` and if the value is `null`, set `"null"` instead. You *could* show us your code, which would increase the chance of getting the desired answer.

Comment: hi @deHaar i added the code to my question.

Comment: Hello! I think you will have to apply any changes in the `DbUtils` class (if you have implemented it yourself), Can you show that code, too? The table is filled by `resultSetToTableModel(s)`.

Comment: DbUtils is a library, i imported it to my class.

Comment: Then it either provides an option of showing `null`, or it doesn't. You will have to have a look into the documentation of the library.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code some data to replace the DB.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly simplest might be a specific table model wrapping the JDBC one.

However changing the display is the general approach:

```
TableCellRenderer old = movieTable.getDefaultRenderer(); // I.o. super?
movieTable.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                                           Object value,
                                           boolean isSelected,
                                           boolean hasFocus,
                                           int row,
                                           int column) {
        boolean notAvailable = value == null;
        if (notAvailable) {
            value = "N/A";
        }
        Component compon = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table,
                                           value,
                                           isSelected,
                                           hasFocus,
                                           row,
                                           column);
        if (notAvailable) {
            compon.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        }
        return compon;
   }
});
```

The problem here, is that there might be several renderers.